# How to combine/gather "medium"s in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm struggling with GA and how to combine two mediums. 
More specifically, I have traffic from two versions of the same newsletter appearing in GA:

- **10122013_This-Is-My-Newsletter-Title. / newsletter_ubivox**
- **10122013_This-Is-My-Newsletter-Title. / (newsletter_ubivox)**

Obviously, this is not desirable. How can i setup a filter (maybe with regex) to combine these two versions into one?

Hopefully, this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Past data is locked down so you can't touch that.

Instead of going into the regex world, could you not edit the tags so the campaign name and medium match? As soon as they match they will start to show as combined in GA.

Easier than filters and new code.

To further expand my answer, you can use an advanced Search and Replace filter to do what you want - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en

I'd set up a test profile first though to make sure that this works as expected.

Comment: While this is true, nice to know you can do it in filters in case you don't have access to the mediums/code (either affiliates and/or different departments)